# POST request does not work at all android

Tags: php, android, mysql, post, server

So I have seen many tutorials to do the POST Request in Android and I have found so many codes but none of them really works and it drives me crazy.

The code does not look false, but I don't know Android is pretty bizarre.

**Here is my Post request in Android:**

```
thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("pseudo","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(edit.getText().toString(),"UTF-8");
            data += "&"+"score"+"="+URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(score),"UTF-8");
            URL url = new URL("http://mywebsite/serveur.php?"+data);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            os.close();
            android.util.Log.d("my Tag",data);
            connection.connect();
            android.content.Intent Npage = new android.content.Intent(SubmiturScore.this, ListOscore.class);
            startActivity(Npage);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**And the server code in PHP to store data in MySQL database:**

```
<?php

$reponse = array();

$pseudo = urldecode($_POST['pseudo']);
$score = intval(urldecode($_POST['score']));

$mysqli = new MySQLi("myhost","myuser","mypassword","mydb");

$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO SIDB (pseudo,score) VALUES('$pseudo',$score)");
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
        . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
if ($result) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "SUCCESS!";

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "FAILURE!";

    echo json_encode($response);
} ?>
```

I have already posted a message in stack overflow but I thought that the code will work but no... Can you please help me !

Comment: Try to change `HttpUrlConnection` to `HttpsUrlConnection`.

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: what error are you getting ? is the php executed at all ? You dont seem to be reading the php script's json output.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I don't think that the php code run because when I try it without android it works.

Comment: You have to encode the question mark `(?)`. your request is not reaching the php code. print the url you are sending to the server i bet it is missing the  question mark `(?)`

Answer (score 0):

So i don't know what the f*** happened with the POST on Android. For resolving my problem I just called a webview that will charge the URL with data so the php script can recuperate data and finally store it in the database...

It was tough but I've finally suceeded YES !

```
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wb.loadUrl("http://yourscript.php?"+data);
```